# Issue when export react-scrollmagic

Tags: reactjs, gsap, scrollmagic

I have an issue, I'm using react-scrollmagic for animate my website, I have the js file with the code and I use "export default functionName"  for export the js to my app.js but it gives me this error "Attempted import error: 'react-scrollmagic' does not contain a default export (imported as 'ScrollMagic')." somebody can help me? There is a way to fix it?

```
    import ScrollMagic from 'react-scrollmagic'

function scrollPhone() {
   const phone = document.querySelector('.phone');
   const video = phone.querySelector('video');
   const txt = phone.querySelector('h1');

   const section = document.querySelector('section');
   const end = section.querySelector('h1');


   const controller= new ScrollMagic.Controller();

   const scene = new ScrollMagic.Scene({
       duration: 9000,
       triggerElement: phone,
       triggerHook: 0,
   })
   .addIndicators()
   .setPin()
   .addTo(controller)
}

export default scrollPhone;
```

Comment: GreenSock doesn't recommend ScrollMagic. Instead they recommend the official scroll plugin: [ScrollTrigger](https://greensock.com/scrolltrigger/)! It's better in every way.

Comment: K, thank you for your answer, I will try!